# Forms of Kashering a knife

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization

I remember hearing that a knife can be kashered (from being *treif*) by sticking it in the ground. But I also know you can use the traditional kashering methods - ***Hag'ala*** (completely submerging the utensil in boiling water) and ***Libun*** (kashering something via heating to a high temperature).

I have 2 questions:

1) What is the logic behind the method of sticking the knife in the ground?

2) When is each method applied?

Answer (score 6):

A knife used for grease is very hard to clean — or was so before modern sponges and cleaning agents. Sticking it in the ground in the prescribed way is (was) a means of cleaning, not *kasher*ing, it. One must then do *libun* or whatever if the knife was used in a way that requires *kasher*ing (*SA [YD](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.121.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)* 121:7).

As always, for a practical ruling, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).

Comment: . . . and thus the ground was expected to wipe off whatever particles were stuck to it.

Comment: And I believe some recommend using a caustic cleaner and steel wool today.

Comment: Libun = putting a flame to the blade of the knife until it gets red hot.